# Tailwind: How to make @apply work for custom CSS class?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Say you have a basic project setup:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And you want to add a basic utility that uses CSS that's not part of tailwinds default library:

```css
@layer utilities {
  .will-change-transform {
    will-change: transform;
  }
}
```

or

```css
@layer utilities {
  .ease {
    transition: ease;
  }
}
```

and you want to be able to `@apply` it to a custom class down the line without receiving an error:

```css
.my-component {
  @apply block hover:scale-110 w-full ease will-change-transform
}
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 5):

I can't say for sure without seeing your environment or the error you were receiving, but [the documented way of circumventing these issues](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#using-apply-with-per-component-css) is to define your classes in your tailwind config file:

```
// tailwind.config.cjs
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  // ...

  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addComponents, theme }) {
      addComponents({
        '.will-change-trans': { // `will-change-transform` is now included in Tailwind CSS 3.0 so using alternative class name for this example
          willChange: 'transform'
        },
        '.ease': {
          transition: 'ease'
        },
      })
    })
  ]

}
```

then you can @apply these classes anywhere as if they were built in.

(I realize that this issue is probably no longer relevant to you, but I found it while searching so this is for anyone else stumbles upon this question!)

Comment: This comment saved me, thanks : ) 
Sucks that I can't @ apply and have to list every single property of every single utility class inside the config file... Think I'll just stick with inlining the utility classes and not using @ apply on them...
(stackoverflow is dumb and won't let me comment unless I put a space after the @ sign)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [postcss extend package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-extend). Prerequisite is tailwind is installed using postcss.

Instead of @apply, one can use @extend to add styles from the custom classes. So the class definition will become something like this -

```
.my-component {
  @apply block hover:scale-110 w-full;
  @extend .ease;
  @extend .will-change-transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom classes inside css and css preprocessors.

I prefer that over defining the custom classes inside `tailwind.config` file, for better file structure and readability.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .will-change-transform {
    will-change: transform;
  }

  .ease {
    transition: ease;
  }
}

/* then... */
.style-this-div {
  @apply will-change-transform ease;
}
```